# Returned struct from DLLs reads garbage if the host definition has constructors

Tags: c++

I have a memory compatible structure on both sides, but if I add constructors to the structure, it results a `Segmentation fault`. My C++ skills are rusty (I've coding Rust too much in the past years), and I need help to understand why it happens.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

// Works without this.
#define CONSTRUCTORS

struct Vec2 {
    float X;
    float Y;
    #ifdef CONSTRUCTORS
    Vec2(float X, float Y): X(X), Y(Y) {}
    Vec2(const Vec2& from): Vec2(from.X, from.Y) {}
    #endif
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto library = LoadLibrary("C:/Users/dangu/dev/revu-design/rust-ue/target/debug/rust_ue.dll");
    std::cout << "Library: " << library << std::endl;
    if (library) {
        auto function = (Vec2 (*)(Vec2, Vec2)) GetProcAddress(library, "rust");
        std::cout << "Function: " << function << std::endl;
        if (function) {
            #ifdef CONSTRUCTORS
            Vec2 a(1.0, 2.0);
            Vec2 b(3.0, 4.0);
            #else
            Vec2 a = { 1.0, 2.0 };
            Vec2 b = { 3.0, 4.0 };
            #endif

            auto result = function(a, b);
            std::cout << result.X << " " << result.Y << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, on MSVC, a POD type that can fit into a register is returned in %rax. A non POD (e.g. with constructor), will always be constructed on the stack, even if it can fit into a register.

Comment: @sbabbi it makes sense. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Define a second type with a conversion operator from `Vec2`.

Comment: C++ doesn't have an ABI. As a corollary Rust [doesn't allow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html) specifying a `C++` ABI. You cannot pass C++ types into a Rust binary (or *any* binary, for that matter, not even a binary compiled from C++ source).

Answer (score 0):

Constructor `Vec2(const Vec2& from): Vec2(X,Y) {}` uses uninitialized `X` an `Y` fields to call another constructor ignoring `from` object. You should really enable warnings when compiling to catch such trivial bugs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I introduced this mistake when writing down the question. With that fix, now it results a SEGMENTATION_FAULT.

Comment: There is no such thing as SEGMENTATION_FAULT on windows. Which error are you actually getting? Does the function signature and struct definition match those on dll side?

Comment: It only prints "Segmentation fault". The DLL is compiled from a Rust code and it has a struct with the exact C representation: `#[repr(C)] struct Vec2 { x: f32, y: f32 }`. The function signature is also matching.

Comment: @Danguafer You said it yourself, it's a struct with the `exact C representation`, not C++, so it just won't work with non POD types.

Comment: @Danguafer Adding constructor to an aggregate C type causes type to become non-aggregate type incompatible with C. Same true for adding destructor or virtual functions.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I was lacking the correct terminology to dive deeper in this matter and I just found this discussion that elucidates it https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/bindgen-and-c/5434/16

Answer (score 0):

As @user7860670 and @sbssa indicated, adding constructors, destructors of virtual functions to a struct cause it to become non-POD (Plain Old Data), and thus not compatible with C.

I also found a deeper discussion about this subject by the Rust community here: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/bindgen-and-c/5434/16